# Reactivemongo - BSONObjectID and BSONDateTime Insertion

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I'm using play2.5 + play2-reactivemongo 0.12.3.

BSONObjectID is inserted as array and BSONDateTime is inserted as NumberLong on mongoDB with following codes.

```
> db.Example.find()
{ "_id" : { "array" : [ 89, 55, -10, 60, -40, 0, 0, -61, 0, -94, 126, 23 ] }, "created" : NumberLong("1496839744818") }
```

I want BSONObjectID to be inserted as ObjectID and DateTime to be inserted as BSONDateTime.
Is it possible to do with type parameter?

TemporalModel.scala

```
trait TemporalModel {
  var _id: Option[BSONObjectID]
  var created: Option[DateTime]
}
```

Example.scala

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
...

case class Example(
  var_id: Option[BSONObjectID],
  str: String,
  var created: Option[DateTime]
) extends TemporalModel

object Example {

  //implicit val objectIdRead: Reads[BSONObjectID] =
  val objectIdRead: Reads[BSONObjectID] =
    (__ \ "$oid").read[String].map { oid =>
      BSONObjectID(oid)
  }

  //implicit val objectIdWrite: Writes[BSONObjectID] = new Writes[BSONObjectID] {
  val objectIdWrite: Writes[BSONObjectID] = new Writes[BSONObjectID] {
    def writes(objectId: BSONObjectID): JsValue = Json.obj(
      "$oid" -> objectId.stringify
    )
  }

  //implicit val dateTimeRead: Reads[DateTime] =
  val dateTimeRead: Reads[DateTime] =
    (__ \ "$date").read[Long].map { dateTime =>
      new DateTime(dateTime)
  }

  //implicit val dateTimeWrite: Writes[DateTime] = new Writes[DateTime] {
  val dateTimeWrite: Writes[DateTime] = new Writes[DateTime] {
    def writes(dateTime: DateTime): JsValue = Json.obj(
      "$date" -> dateTime.getMillis
    )
  }

  implicit val objectIdFormats = Format(objectIdRead, objectIdWrite)
  implicit val dateTimeFormats = Format(dateTimeRead, dateTimeWrite)
  //implicit val bsonObjectIDJsonFormat = Json.format[BSONObjectID]
  implicit val exampleJsonFormat = Json.format[Example]

  def apply(str: String): Example = {
    new Example(null, str, null)
  }
}
```

BaseDAO.scala

```
class BaseDAO[T] {
  ...
  val collectionName: String
  lazy val collection: Future[JSONCollection] = reactiveMongoApi.database.map(_.collection(collectionName))

  def toJs[K : Writes](o: K) = Json.toJson(o).as[JsObject]

  def insert(document: T)(implicit writer: Writes[T]): Future[T] = {
    document._id = Some(BSONObjectID.generate)
    document.created = Some(DateTime.now)
    collection.flatMap(_.insert(toJs(document)))
  }
}
```

ExampleDAO.scala

```
trait ExampleDAO extends BaseDAO[Example]

class ExampleDAOImpl @Inject() (val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi) 
extends ExampleDAO {
  val collectionName = "example"
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but you could replace `Writes` with `OWrites` for `toJs` parameter `K`, to make sure that `as[JsObject]` won't throw an exception.

Comment: Could you explain what doesn't suit you in the code you wrote?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I want "_id" in Example case class to be inserted as ObjectID but it's inserted as array and also want "created" to be inserted as ISODate. it's inserted as NumberLong with my code.

Comment: Does `objectId.stringify` really convert the `BSONObjectID` to a hash string? Not tested but i think `BSONObjectID` as a binary data is converted to array from my analysis. Why dont you use `toString`

Comment: I also tried toString. But, the result was the same as stringify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have too many implicits in-scope. However, since those are resolved in the macro, there seems to be no compilation error.

What you should do:

- remove all `implicit` modifiers in front of your `Reads` and `Writes` for `BSONObjectID` and `DateTime`
- remove `bsonObjectIDJsonFormat` (which has same type as `objectIdFormats`, so this should not be allowed by the compiler)

Comment: I commented out all implicit. But nothing change.

Comment: Do not remove everything, just the word `implicit` in front of your 4 
`Reads` and `Writes` (keep the `Format`s) and `bsonObjectIDJsonFormat`

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood. And it's not resolved with modified code. Am I missing something?

Comment: I modified some codes and been trying to resolve the problem. But, still doesn't work as I expect.

Comment: that's weird, I have the same code as you have in `Example.scala`, and It serializes `Example`s as you want them. Have you tried to pass the `Writes[Example]` explicitly to your `insert` method, to see if it really uses`exampleJsonFormat`?

Comment: I added println() into objectIdWrite and I confirmed it doesn't output via test code. really weird.

Comment: You should check, say with IntelliJ, what implicit is used when you call insert.

Comment: sorry. I just confirmed println is called once with specs2 test. IntelliJ? my development environment is on ubuntu and vim..

Comment: It's properly inserted as I expected!! The problem was that I was confirming via embedded mongodb flapdoodle with specs2. I don't know why test code let the data insert real mongodb.. Anyway, really thanks a lot. I realized it after I installed IntelliJ on mac. It's quite useful.